# Getting started with Zend Framework 1

Tags: php, windows, zend-framework, xampp

I've just heard about ZF and it's been kicking my butt all day (it's almost 11pm right now)...

I've added an include for ZF in my php.ini file and I've created environment variables for ZF and PHP:

User Variable (name : value)

> ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH : C:\xampp\ZendFramework-1.12.3\bin

System Variable (name : value)

> Path : C:\xampp\php\

When I try to run `zf create project quickstart` from my command line, I get an error telling me about using the User Variable I've already set:

> The easiest way to get the zf command running is to give it the include path via an environment variable ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH or ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH_PREPEND with the proper include path to use, then run the command "zf --setup".

I'm really at a loss as to what I'm supposed to do here or whether or not I've done something wrong...

Can anyone give any advice?

Comment: Sounds like it wants you to run `zf --setup`

Comment: @acobster I get the same error when I try it

Comment: If you're just getting started I'd really suggest looking at ZF2 (the current version) rather than ZF1 (which is what you appear to be trying)

Comment: from INSTALL.txt: `If you would like to use Zend_Tool, simply add bin/zf.bat (for Windows) or
bin/zf.sh (for anything else) to your system executable path`

Comment: @TimFountain okay so now I've got 2.2.4, extracted to my xampp folder... now what? I've been told to use the composer, but all I have is a .json file that I can't do anything with

Comment: I'd recommend following the tutorial: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Comment: Ahhh documentation! handy and forgettable documentation.